# Classification tree simulation study in R

Tags: tree, classification, cart, rpart

I am trying to figure out how to write code to generate data from a classification tree for a simulation study. Let's say I have 3 multivariate normal random variables. I would generate them in `R` using the following code,

```
set.seed(1612)
library(MASS)
Sigma <- matrix(c(0.277312, 0.1213606, 0.05482612, 0.1213606, 0.5968614, 0.2171699, 0.05482612, 0.2171699, 0.5036522), nrow = 3)
X  <- mvrnorm(n = 1272, mu = rep(0, 3), Sigma = Sigma)
colnames(X) <- paste0("X", 1:3)
pred <- data.frame(X)
```

Then I would like to classify Y as **yes** (i.e., 1) based on the following rules:

- If X1 <= 0 and X2 <= 0
- If X1 > 0 and X3 <= 0

I would do this with the following code and fit the tree using `rpart`.

```
y <- ifelse(pred$X1 <= 0 & pred$X2 <= 0, 1, ifelse(pred$X1 > 0 & pred$X3 <= 0, 1, 0))
library(rpart)
mod <- rpart(y ~ ., data = pred, method = "class")
mod

mod
n= 1272 

node), split, n, loss, yval, (yprob)
     * denotes terminal node

1) root 1272 636 0 (0.5000000 0.5000000)  
 2) X3>=-0.001090791 663 126 0 (0.8099548 0.1900452)  
  4) X2>=-0.002500219 420   0 0 (1.0000000 0.0000000) *
  5) X2< -0.002500219 243 117 1 (0.4814815 0.5185185)  
   10) X1>=0.001410812 117   0 0 (1.0000000 0.0000000) *
   11) X1< 0.001410812 126   0 1 (0.0000000 1.0000000) *
3) X3< -0.001090791 609  99 1 (0.1625616 0.8374384)  
  6) X2>=0.00167211 227  99 1 (0.4361233 0.5638767)  
   12) X1< -0.000418794 99   0 0 (1.0000000 0.0000000) *
   13) X1>=-0.000418794 128   0 1 (0.0000000 1.0000000) *
 7) X2< 0.00167211 382   0 1 (0.0000000 1.0000000) *
```

However, I don't seem to be able to exactly recover my tree (note that x3 occurs at the top of the tree). I believe I am generating data incorrectly but I am not sure how to properly generate data. Should I be generating data for X conditional on Y or vice versa (as I've done here). I also know I have no error in my Y at present and could introduce error if I set Y to be a Bernoulli random variable with a probability near 1 for my conditions (this, however, doesn't seem to correct my problem).

Any help would be welcomed as I couldn't find anything in my searches..

Comment: Is there really a function `mvnrorm` or do you mean `rmvnorm` from the mvtnorm package?

Comment: Sorry, this was indeed a typo. Do you have any thoughts about my principal question?

Comment: I am not sure that I see the problem. If I change your statement to `X  <- rmvnorm(n = 1272, mean = rep(0, 3), sigma = Sigma)`  (three typos corrected) and run the rest, I get a good tree out of `rpart`. what is not working?

Comment: I am not using the `mvtnorm` package. As I mentioned, I am using `MASS`. There are no typos in my code at this point.